# Не могу открыть картинку на localhost (формата jpeg)

Tags: c++

возник вопрос, написал я такой себе сервер. Если я запрашиваю картинку, то получаю следующее:[image]
Чтение для открытия HTML страниц вопросов не вызывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью этого кода я читаю файл:

```
ifstream f(text);
            if (f.good())
            {
                string str((istreambuf_iterator<char>(f)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
                answer = str;
                code = 200;
            }
            f.close();
```

И отправляю ответ клиенту:

```
ostringstream response << "HTTP/1.1 " << code << " OK\r\n" // code - 200 или 404
                << "Version: HTTP / 1.1\r\n"
                << "Content-Type: " << s // запрашиваемый файл
                << "Content-Length: " << answer.length() // длина строки
                << "\r\n\r\n"
                << answer; // строка для чтения

send(client_socket, response.str().c_str(), response.str().length(), 0);
```

В случае отправки картинки:

```
s = "image/jpeg;\r\n";
```

Как мне прочитать картинку и записать в строку? Или лучше отвечать html страничкой (к которой прикреплен файл)? Спасибо!)

Comment: Файл jpeg, сейчас немного подправлю вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь с бинарным файлом (png) обращаться так же, как и с символьной строкой. Однако в строке байт 0 является завершающим символом, а файле png нулевые байты идут начиная с позиции 8. Соответственно у вас передаются только первые 8 байт, а это `‰PNG` плюс пара переводов строки. Что мы и наблюдаем на ваших скриншотах. Решение: вместо строки использовать массив байт, в котором 0 не рассматривается как ограничитель.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Пример программы, которая читает в массив некий png (просто читает и все):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  const filesystem::path fileName = LR"(C:\Temp\cmmentics.png)";
  auto fileSize = filesystem::file_size(fileName);

  vector<char> fileBuffer(fileSize);

  ifstream is(fileName, ios::binary);
  is.read(fileBuffer.data(), fileSize);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сейчас гляну, спасибо)

Comment: ifstream g(text, ios::binary);
    g.read((char*)&answer, sizeof(answer));
    g.close();
    code = 200;

Comment: вот так начал читать, к прочитанному добавился знак вопроса

Comment: byte answer[1000] = {};

Comment: @Алексей Журко, не понял ваши комментарии - вы что-то спрашиваете? Если так, то лучше всего дополнить ваш вопрос (нажмите "править" под вопросом).

Comment: Простите, не могли бы Вы написать как считать файл в массив байт. Я попытался, но код выше почти ничего не изменил, просто после %PNG появился знак вопроса в рамке. Спасибо

Comment: @Алексей Журко, дополнил ответ примером.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!) Все работает)

Comment: @Алексей Журко, если ответ вас устроил, отметьте его как принятый, пожалуйста.